# Как взять данные с сайта и добавить в приложение?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

В приложении есть WebView.. мне нужно, чтобы в приложении выводилась статистика из сайта, загруженного в WebView. Статистика уже есть на сайте, например кол-во посещений: 100. Я хочу чтобы пользователь смог получить эту информацию в приложении в более удобном формате. На сайте, через "просмотреть код" в Chrome я навел на эти данные на сайте, и он мне выдал такой код:`<td class="textright"><b>100</b></td>` т.е. я так понял это не тот код, который мне нужен. Да и вообще это реально сделать?

Comment: Реально. Почему вы считаете, что то, что вы нашли - не то, что вам надо?

Comment: Хорошо, а как я смогу использовать этот код, который я нашёл, чтобы вывести его в TextView в приложении?

Comment: Ну... Вам надо получить страницу в виде `HTML` кода и далее его распарсить чтобы вытащить нужное. Для этого можно взять либу `JSOUP`.

Comment: Вот здесь посмотри http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/